# Ubuntu 14.04.01 doesn't boot on Toshiba after wiping out Windows 8

Tags: 14.04, windows-8

New laptop (Toshiba Satellite) with windows 8 installed.
Wiped out windows 8.
Disabled Secure boot
UEFI mode
Ran Boot-repair. results: (http://paste.ubuntu.com/9837456/) 
Reboots back to trying to boot in PXE
Help please. 
Thanks you

Answer (score 0):

Well, have you disabled the PXE boot too?
You most probably have an option in the boot menu for pxe boot. You should go there and disable it, just like u did with the 'secure boot'.

To enter boot menu press f12 when at startup or when the logo (if there is a logo) of toshiba pops up.

Comment: Thank you for your response. I don't know how to disable PXE boot from BIOS menu, but my boot order lists LAN as the last option. It doesn't look like there is more I can do with that.

Comment: in my bios, that option is under the "boot" section.
since we might not have the same bios, please tell me the version and name of your bios (written either at the very top of the bios window or at the bottom).

Comment: Version is 1.3, but I'm not sure about the name. this link point to the bios I am using and that is my machine model: http://support.toshiba.com/support/modelHome?freeText=1200008322

Comment: I found LAN Setting on BIOS and disabled it. Rebooted, and it displays "Reboot and select proper Boot Device or Insert Boot Media in Selected Boot Device and press a key". Thanks

Comment: nice! so the issue is solved, right?

Comment: No. It's not resolved yet. it's still asking for proper boot device which is the Hard drive, but it doesn't think so obviously.

Comment: Well you said that you have wiped out windows 8, right?

Was there any operating system on the hard drive, besides windows 8? Because if there wasn't, the laptop has nothing to boot from, cuz there's no operating system on the harddrive. Which means you must install one, in order to boot from the harddrive and for the laptop to be functional.

Comment: i do have ubuntu 14.04 installed on the hard drive

Comment: Sorry about the confusion. I did install Ubuntu 14.04 on the hard drive.

Comment: i don't know what to say from this point on, hope someone will. check out youtube, maybe it helps